# iOS / Objective-C Meta Class and Category

Tags: ios, objective-c, metaclass, objective-c-runtime, objective-c-category

I understand a class is actually an object / typedef of struct (`objc_class*)`.
Each class has a "backing" meta class, which in turns has a isa pointer pointing to the meta class of `NSObject`.

And `NSObject`basically has a isa pointer pointing back to itself.

And we could get a hold of the meta class via this line:

```
objc_getMetaClass("<CLASS_NAME>");
```

I hope my understanding of meta class is not off here so far (please correct me if it is).

**My questions are:**

*1.)*

> When would we need to deal with meta class? Could you please cite an
>   example / a scenario in code when we might need to?

*2.)*

**Background:**

I was thinking freely about third party libraries and how they are structured.

Usually they provide you with a class method and return you a class and all other methods are private / "hidden". And most of the time, while they can be subclassed but since we do not know the `init` method, it would be of no use to subclass.

And suddenly I began thinking about *Objective-C Category* and thus leading me to think of *Objective-C meta class*.

And this leads to my question #2:

> Is it possible to break this structure by making use of *Objective-C
>   Category* and / or with the use of *meta class* (by grabbing a hold of
>   it and insert a class method straight there in the meta class)? Or
>   even look up the name of their instance methods that are private?

My intention here is not to "break" anything, I am just very curious as to how "unbreakable" these third party libraries are structured and if their structures cannot be "broken" via the use of *Category* and *Meta Class*.

**@Leo Natan:**

***1.)***

What is `method_*()`?

***2.)***

For the **love of Objective-C Runtime**:

Could you cite an example implementation-swizzling an instance method, let say,

(*I am not sure if this method is a good example, for we could override it in the first place*)

`NSArray`'s `-count` instance method (let’s make it so that it returns always count 100, for example)

***3.)***

So in theory all classes (including all third party libraries) can be break (broken)? Other words, there is ***no way to create a „call-only-this-class-method-or-you-cannot-use-me“ API / library***?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just a small suggestion: if your goal is to inject or list methods of third party ObjC libraries, you can simply use objective c runtime ;-) https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: @LombaX Thanks for information - I didn't know that would be possible using Objective-C Runtime. ;-) Again, I am not trying to break something - I really want to learn more about what I mentioned in my post and if someday it would be my turn to create a third party library / API, I could make a decent one by first knowing how they / their structures can be broken. Again, thanks. Will definitely read more about Objective-C Runtime as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meta class is useful when wishing to view, add or modify class methods and class-level information.

For example,

```
    IMP myIMP = imp_implementationWithBlock(^(id _self, NSString *string) {
        NSLog(@"Hello %@", string);
    });
    Class cls = objc_getMetaClass("NSString");
    class_addMethod(cls, @selector(test:), myIMP, "v@:@");
    [NSString test:@"lala"];
```

To get instance methods, you use `class_copyMethodList()` on the class returned by `class` method on an object or `NSClassFromString()`. You will get an array of all the instance methods defined by the class (but not of its superclass!). You can then use the various `method_*()` methods to retrieve information and possibly even modify these methods (like implementation swizzling).

You can call `class_copyMethodList()` on the meta class to get all the class methods defined.

To address your "Leo" questions,

1.
Please read the [Objective C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/objcruntimeref/Reference/reference.html). You can find a section of `method_` functions dealing with `Method` structs.

2.
See [tutorial](http://darkdust.net/writings/objective-c/method-swizzling) on implementation swizzling.

3.
Using Objective C, everything is available to the runtime. It goes without saying, that with great power comes great responsibility. The Objective C runtime is very powerful. These swizzles are very dangerous and usually not recommended.

Comment: @Dvole The Objective C runtime is very interesting! :-)

Comment: @LeoNatan +1 Not only very interesting, but **very very** interesting. I  still have some problem understanding what you have mentioned (excuse me), I will update my question with a message to you, I hope you could further shed some light on those. Thanks in advance.

Comment: very nice! logical but never used it like this. cool to see it

Comment: @LeoNatan Super.. ah, just one more thing, that avatar in the swizzling website is not _you_ (your SO avatar looks about the same as that, hence my question), right? :-) Just curiosity. Will mark this as answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Unheilig Not me. :-)